# How to display coordinates within a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to display the coordinates of a matrix in terms of X and Y. For example

```
if matrix = [ 0 0 5 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0]
```

Say, i want the coordinate for 5...how can i write a code that says `5 = 1x and 3 y`.

I don't want to display the element in the matrix, just the coordinates of that element.

Answer (score 2):

use `find`

```
[y x] = find( matrix ~= 0 ); % gives you the x y coordinates of all non-zero elements
```

Note the order of `y` and `x`, since Matlab is indexing using row-column.

Comment: Or if you just want to find the five, it is of course `find(matrix == 5)`